# jQuery date picker showing blank textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to use jquery datepicker. Though I'm new to jQuery, I have looked at similar implementations, but mine still showing empty textbox.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testing.aspx.cs" Inherits="healthcare.testing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
<script>

    $(function ()
    {

        $("#<%=txtdisplaydate.ClientID%>").datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdisplaydate" runat="server" />
    </div>
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The default behaviour is to show a blank text box *until* you click it. Does clicking it do anything?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, I Actually clicked on the textbox but nothing showup

Comment: Did you check the browser console?

Comment: @Freak_Droid, Display the following error messages:Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js:315
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined testing.aspx:13
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder what "jQuery is not defined" could mean. Most puzzling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testing.aspx.cs" Inherits="healthcare.testing" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

        $(function ()
        {

            $("#<%=txtdisplaydate.ClientID%>").datepicker();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
     <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdisplaydate" runat="server" />
        </div>
       </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```